# Javascript - transform a range of numbers into another range

Tags: javascript

On a conference device from Cisco, i am currently programming a UI element where the user can set the Brightness via a slider. The slider returns a values from 0 to 255 when dragged. However, the brightness configuration only accepts values from 1 to 31 (minimum to maximum brightness). How can i "transform" this? I could do it via quick and dirty maths by dividing the output by 9 and round up to the next integer, so the slider goes from 1 to 29, but that would be quite a messy solution, and i was hoping that there is a better, more dynamic way (so that i can adapt it quickly if, in the future, a similar slider has to be used on another variable with a different range)

Comment: This _is_ pretty basic math … So what is the problem? Are you having trouble coming up with the correct formula, or what?

Comment: You could calculate the percentage. 1 is 0% and 255/31 are 100%

Comment: @CBroe of course its basic. add one, divide by 9 and round up. but that isnt very exact, and not dynamic, as i said pretty clearly in my question

Comment: @NullDev how would i do this?

Comment: I wasn’t referring to your inexact approximation when I said “basic”, but I meant doing the actual math to proportionally transfer the value from the source interval into the target interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First pretend that your target range is 0-30 instead of 1-31. This should be very easy to convert:

```
[0-255] / 255 * 30 = [0-30]
```

Then add one. Done!

```
[0-255] / 255 * 30 + 1 = [1-31]
```

You can round this to the nearest integer, it doesn't matter that much, it'll always be in the range.

Answer (score 3):

You can go through percentages and then (if appropriate) `Math.round`, see comments:

```
function mapValue(value, fromRange, toRange) {
    const {min: fromMin, max: fromMax} = fromRange;
    const {min: toMin, max: toMax} = toRange;
    // Determine how wide the ranges are
    const fromSize = fromMax - fromMin;
    const toSize   = toMax   - toMin;
    // Get the percentage of the original range `value` represents, ignoring the minimum value
    const fromPercent = (value - fromMin) / fromSize;
    // Get the corresponding percentage of the new range, plus its minimum value
    const result = (fromPercent * toSize) + toMin;
    return result;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function mapValue(value, fromRange, toRange) {
    const {min: fromMin, max: fromMax} = fromRange;
    const {min: toMin, max: toMax} = toRange;
    // Determine how wide the ranges are
    const fromSize = fromMax - fromMin;
    const toSize   = toMax   - toMin;
    // Get the percentage of the original range `value` represents, ignoring the minimum value
    const fromPercent = (value - fromMin) / fromSize;
    // Get the corresponding percentage of the new range, plus its minimum value
    const result = (fromPercent * toSize) + toMin;
    return result;
}

const fromRange = {min: 0, max: 255};
const toRange   = {min: 1, max: 31};
function test(value) {
    const result = Math.round(mapValue(value, fromRange, toRange));
    console.log(`${value} => ${result}`);
}

test(0);
test(127);
test(128);
test(255);
```

That's very general purpose, but you can do it specifically for your ranges like this:

```
function mapSliderToBrightness(value) {
    return (value / 255) * 30 + 1;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function mapSliderToBrightness(value) {
    return (value / 255) * 30 + 1;
}

function test(value) {
    const result = Math.round(mapSliderToBrightness(value));
    console.log(`${value} => ${result}`);
}

test(0);
test(127);
test(128);
test(255);
```

Comment: Very useful, for linear work that is :)